# mysql join - select col1 where col2 matches a (filtered) col in other table

Tags: mysql, join

Here's what I want to do:

1. `select tableB.column1 WHERE tableB.column2 = some_var`
2. `select tableA.column1 WHERE tableA.column2 was a result from step one.`

Can this be done in one select? What's the best way to do this, especially performance-wise? I'm using PHP.

**EDIT:**
I have a conversation based messaging system. 1 `convo table` and 1 `replies table`. Replies table includes columns: `responder and convo_id`. To load convo I get all replies with that convo_id.

I want to use the convoId to get all responders to that convo, and go into usertable and select all the avatars of responders, then store the avatars in array and echo them out as needed.

Comment: I think a little bit more information would help. Really depends on what A is dependent on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try the following sql statement

```
SELECT u.avatar
FROM usertable u
JOIN replies r ON u.responder_id = r.responder_id
WHERE r.convo_id = 1234
```

this will get all the avatars of the users who participated in the conversation with id 1234

Comment: Thanks everyone for answers. This answer does it for me, as it uses a where on convo_id. I'll also be using DISTINCT with select, since I'll reuse the avatars of same user.

Comment: What is the shorthand you're using? "usertable u". is that for performance or just readability? can someone link me the docs on it. I don't know what it's called.

Comment: I believe they are called alias names.  I don't believe they impact performance but are generally used for readability since table names could be either non descriptive or just plain long.  As you correctly pointed out, DISTINCT would be necessary since my SQL statement would give repeated avatars.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
select a.Column1 
FROM tableA a 
LEFT JOIN tableB b ON a.Column2 = b.Column1
```

You could also use subquery, but that's less performant.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I decided to go with. It builds an array ($avatars) where keys are usernames and values are avatars.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 
    DISTINCT users.avatar,replies.sender 
    FROM users 
    JOIN replies 
    ON users.username = replies.sender 
    WHERE replies.convo_id = '$convoID'
");
while($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $avatars[$array['sender']] = $array['avatar'];
}
```

Comment: convoID is a hex string, so is in quotes. I mislead by saying I only was selecting from one column. I didn't realize.